# How to set IE as a default browser in IIS 6.1?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, iis-6, hosting

Am using the IIS 6.1 for host the Asp.net web site.If i browse the website in IIS it will open in the chrome.Now I need when I use the Browse in IIs I want the Website will Open in the Internet Explorer?How to set IE as a default browser in IIS 6.1 ? at the time of Browse.What are the changes are need in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The web server has no control over what browsers will access your website.
In case you are talking about the Visual Studio development server that opens a browser when you run your web-project, you can change your default browser in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

This is not an IIS setting, it is your Default Browser setting.

Modify this from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs (Windows 7)

Comment: http://www.guidingtech.com/6579/change-default-browser-make-firefox-chrome-ie-default-browser/

Answer (score 2):

Yo can follow these steps to set default browser for IIS:

Open the settings in google chrome and follow below screen shots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't control it from IIS, it is basically your windows setting that which browser is your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need change on your operating system the default browser.

Answer (score -1):

Super old question, but the answers here are wrong now. In Visual Studio, you have the option to choose your browser for projects that aren't made from a version that uses IIS express, and that option will override your default browser and Visual Studio will use that option for subsequent builds of projects that use IIS express. I haven't found if this option lives anywhere but those projects, but I will update if you can.